# Change variable depending on newcomers

Tags: r

I have the following dataset (or rather an extract of a huge dataset).

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Month = c(1,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,6),
  Buyer = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A", "A","A", "A"),
  Seller = c("C","C","C","D","C","D","C","D", "C", "D", "E"),
  Incumbent = c(1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0)
  )
View(Data)
```

I need to create the column `incumbent`: it needs to take the value 1 if the seller is a seller with a relationship history with the firm and 0 else. A new seller becomes an incumbent as soon as a new seller comes and himself becomes an incumbent.

Is there an easy way to do this ?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, could you specify your explanation? A seller becomes an incumbent in the second month of doing business? I.e. seller "D" becomes an incumbent in month 4.

Comment: @AdriaanNeringBögel thanks for the question, a seller becomes an incumbent if he is the first here, like Seller C or if a new Seller comes in, , i.e. Seller D becomes an incumbent in Period 6 because Seller E arrives in period 6. Is it clearer ?

Comment: it is! Unfortunately it makes answering your question harder for me. I will have to think on it for a while.